# CSS two colums is breaking my layout

Tags: html, css

I have page that loads data in dynamically. I have put the image on the left and some text on the right. In two column by using float:left; 
This works fine but the height of the containing div does not change to match the height of the larger div.

I have soemthing like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">//some php to load image</div>
   <div class="right">//loaded text</div>
</div>

.container{
   width:800px;
   height:auto;
}
.left,.right{
  float:left;
  height:auto;
}
.left{
   width:300px;
}
.right{
   width:500px;
}
```

The divs are next to eachother but the containing div only resizes to the height of the smallest div. Shouldn't it resize to the height of the largest div?

Comment: you need to [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) your floats

Comment: a combination of the two works well, clear the floats and add overflow:auto to the container. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:auto` to the `.container` element..

Comment: this works but surely that what just add a scroll bar

Comment: @PaulLedger, it doesn't add a scrollbar. it will just expand the container to the height of the child elements.. a scrollbar would appear only if you manually set a height to the container..

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a typical `clearfix` problem.

Read here about clearfix: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)